# Formulate SQL query

Tags: sql

Iam new to SQL and I have to create SQL statement to select from following tables:

```
studentTable (studentID, firstName, lastName)

enrollmentTable (studentID, courseID, semester, year, grade)
```

(studentID and courseID are foreign keys)

```
courseTable (courseID, semester, year, name)

prereqTable (courseID, prereqID)
```

I have to select students that enrolled course but don't have fulfilled all prereq.

EDIT:

After a while I got the right solution. The key was to use multiple selects and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried to do inner join prereqTable and enrollmentTable on courseIDs that gave me results for courses with prereqs. Than I have select that gave me students and enrollments that have F grade or didn't finished course. I dont know how to get the final result from these 2...

Comment: ... or http://www.sql-join.com/ or ... whatever you find when searching for "SQL tutorial join". When you ask a question here, you should at least show the efforts you have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I got the right solution.
The key was to use multiple selects and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM studentTable
         WHERE EXISTS(
           SELECT * FROM enrollmentTable, prereqTable 
                    WHERE enrollmentTable.studentID = studentTable.studentID  
                      AND prereqTable.courseID = enrollmentTable.courseID 
                      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM enrollmentTable 
                                              WHERE enrollmentTable.courseID = prereqTable.prereqID
                                                AND enrollmentTable.studentID = studentTable.studentId)
         )
```